# I'm trying to setup a webhook eventsub from the Twitch API using ngrok as a gateway

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webhooks, twitch

When i trigger a test event using the Twitch CLI i get an error response back saying:
`Post "https://1562-5-182-32-19.ngrok.io/api/twitch/eventsub/": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)` 
The notification events for my twitch channel reward redemption were working a few hours ago, but now I am getting 502 gateway error messages from ngrok and time out issues as well.

when i ping ngrok.com i get this:
`Pinging ngrok.com [54.190.89.62] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 54.190.89.62:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),`

I also have cert.pem csr.pem and key.pem files located in a cert directory, but i'm not to sure what to do with those either.

I am just confuzzledd because it was working earlier today

I tried directly providng the localhost route in the ngrok command like so:
`ngrok http https://localhost:8888` but the same errors occur

i made sure my subscriptions were still active and they are:
      `status: 'enabled', type: 'channel.channel_points_custom_reward_redemption.add',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sigh... I needed to dump the current subscription list and re-create new subscriptions with the NEW ngrok link.